# How can I prevent a constant toggle of hover state caused by box-shadow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Check out this jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/dnGQE/1/) I am using box-shadow to get a groovy 3D look (don't worry, I used different colors on the real version), but when you hover over the box-shadow lines, the hover state keeps toggling on and off, which is super annoying. You have to be kind-of specific with your mouse to get this to happen, but nonetheless, I don't like it. I have tried using jQuery hover() and hoverIntent() which slows down the toggling but doesn't solve the problem. One potential cause is the negative margin-top on hover, but I don't want to get rid of this. Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="navLink">
    <a>Samples</a>
</div>
<div class="navLink">
    <a>HTML</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navLink {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.navLink a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 10px 16px 10px;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: aqua;
}
.navLink a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px -1px blue, 0px 1px 0px 0px green, -1px 1px 0px 0px blue, -1px 2px 0px 0px green, -2px 2px 0px 0px blue, -2px 3px 0px 0px green, -3px 3px 0px 0px blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -3px -3px 0px 3px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Nothing such happens in my browser.

Comment: I'm more than sure it's caused by the negative margin, as you tell the element to "move" on mouse hover. I'm using latest version of FF and no flashing happens as well.
Get rid of the negative margin. Or you can add a margin to anchor tag when it's not hovered.

Comment: What browser are you using? I am using Chrome, but it is kinda hard to get it to happen...

Comment: I tested that, this happens in `Chrome` (most annoying), `Opera` (hard to invoke but possible). `Firefox` is just ok.

Comment: Any specific reason to keep negative margin top? without that it works fine `//margin: -3px -3px 0px 3px;`

Comment: Yeah, it's not the box shadow that causes this, it's the margin.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: fixed height is also necessary, as noted in the comments (thanks Blazemonger):

Switch this:

```
.navLink {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.navLink a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px -1px blue, 0px 1px 0px 0px green, -1px 1px 0px 0px blue, -1px 2px 0px 0px green, -2px 2px 0px 0px blue, -2px 3px 0px 0px green, -3px 3px 0px 0px blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -3px -3px 0px 3px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

To this:

```
.navLink {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.navLink:hover a {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px -1px blue, 0px 1px 0px 0px green, -1px 1px 0px 0px blue, -1px 2px 0px 0px green, -2px 2px 0px 0px blue, -2px 3px 0px 0px green, -3px 3px 0px 0px blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -3px -3px 0px 3px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

This way the hover is applied over the entire item on hover, not just on the a tag. I updated your jsFiddle, to make sure it works for what you are looking for.

Comment: You also need to add a fixed height to the `.navLink` element so it doesn't resize on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dnGQE/2/

Comment: guys be nice! i added the explanation after posting, to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using jQuery `.hover()` and assigning/removing a class on the **parent** --

I know you said you tried jQuery already, but you probably used it on the `a` -- the problem is that your `a` element moves, but the parent will not move, so use the parent's static position to fix your issue.

Your css would then be kind of like this:

```
.navLink a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 10px 16px 10px;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: aqua;
}
.navLink-hover a, .navLink a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px -1px blue, 0px 1px 0px 0px green, -1px 1px 0px 0px blue, -1px 2px 0px 0px green, -2px 2px 0px 0px blue, -2px 3px 0px 0px green, -3px 3px 0px 0px blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -3px -3px 0px 3px;
    background: blue;
}
```

And your jQuery would look like this:

```
$(".navLink-hover").hover( function() {
  $(this).addClass(".navLink-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass(".navLink-hover");
});
```

Comment: lol -- certainly the easy answer -- you could also use a psuedoclass on the parent...

Comment: also -- jquery tends to be the answer most often when you tag your question with "jquery" :)

Comment: Thanks, but LifeInTheGrey's answer works with only CSS, much preferred!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the hover state to the parent :

```
.navLink:hover a {
```

and change the margin, but only the bottom :

```
margin: -3px -3px 3px 3px;
```

it works ok.

If changing the bottom margin is not ok, then you can make differents layouts. The only critical point is making the size of the div constant